# Почему Сhrome показывает ошибку? JavaScript setAttribute()

Tags: javascript

Почему в консоли Сhrome отображается ошибка JavaScript:

**attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "NaN,1".**

```
<video id="vd" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4"></video>
<div id="prg">
    <svg id="ldPrg"><path id="prgB" d=""/></svg>
</div>
```

Сам JS код. Если все переменные кроме `cnv` заменить имеющимися вычеслениями и удалить `-strt`, то всё работает, но отрисавывает не корректно.

```
vd.onprogress=function(){
    for(i=0;i<vd.buffered.length;i++){
        cnv=prg.clientWidth/vd.duration;
        strt=vd.buffered.start(i)*cnv;
        prgB.setAttribute('d',prgB.getAttribute('d')+'M'+strt+',1'+' '+vd.buffered.end(i)*cnv-strt+',1')
    }
}
```

```js
vd.onprogress = function() {
  console.log('vd.onprogress');
  for (let i = 0; i < vd.buffered.length; i++) {
    let cnv = prg.clientWidth / vd.duration;
    let strt = vd.buffered.start(i) * cnv;
    let value = prgB.getAttribute('d') + 'M' + strt + ',1' + ' ' + vd.buffered.end(i) * cnv - strt + ',1';
    console.log(prgB.getAttribute('d'), cnv, strt, value);
    prgB.setAttribute('d', value);
  }
}
```

```html
<video id="vd" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4" style="width:240px"></video>
<div id="prg">
  <svg id="ldPrg"><path id="prgB" d=""/></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну поставь брейкпоинт на установку атрибута и посмотри, что туда пишется.

Comment: Первый раз столкнулся за всё время когда ни какие манипуляции не помогают. Я чесно не знаю как ставить брейкпоинт и куда смотреть... ( Подожди если хочешь - может кто ответит тоже. Мне если честно - не горит, у меня другая альтернатива есть, просто более сложная.

Comment: На вот эту строку `prgB.setAttribute('d'` и смотри значение, которое присваиваешь.

Comment: @Igor сорри за отказ от твоего сниппета. Просто тут всё-равно консоли нет и ошибок не видно.

Comment: В Firefox консоли ошибок нет, но всё равно не работает.

Comment: @AlexanderV.Ulyanov тут консоль есть

Comment: @Igor сейчас опять порылся - не могу найти (.

Comment: @AlexanderV.Ulyanov Добавил фрагмент кода.

Comment: @Igor Сасибо! Всё работает. Временные точки пошли - то что нужно было. А у меня всё ломалось и скрипт как положено стопорился. Понял про консоль здесь - Спасибо ещё раз. Всё равно в Хром ошибка и скрипт не работает, но показалось несколько таймпоинтов.

Comment: @AlexanderV.Ulyanov Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Comment: @Igor видимо тайпоинты появились из-за console.log(). Цитата: ↑ ...в Хром ошибка и скрипт не работает...